# How to disable .zsh_history & .zsh_sessions on macOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

By default in macOS zsh stores the history and sessions in the `~/.zsh_history` & `~/.zsh_sessions` files.

However for one of my computers I want no Terminal/zsh history or session to be stored what so ever.

Is there a way to disable this behavior in zsh?

Answer (score 1):

OK... Let me say this up front - in a *blockquote* to set it apart:

> *The answer to your question (and other `zsh` configuration questions) is dependent upon which macOS version you're using, and which terminal application you use. It is my **opinion** that Apple's well-intentioned (perhaps?), but ill-advised overreach is responsible for these dependencies. By this, I only mean to say that `zsh` is well-documented, and completely capable of handling your HISTORY preferences without any assistance from Apple. Yet, by their choosing to add **their** defaults to `/etc/zshrc` and `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` Apple makes it more difficult for users to change `zsh` defaults.*
> <sup>[REFERENCE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427568/149366)</sup>

All of that said, I don't know which macOS version you're running, and as my macOS is 10.15 Catalina, I couldn't verify my answer will work on your system. Also: this answer is partially redundant with an [earlier answer on a similar topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/399023/149366), and so please refer to that answer for details I've omitted here.

#### Proposed Answer: Set `SAVEHIST=0` and `HISTSIZE=0`

Open the file `~/.zshrc` in your editor, and add (or modify if they exist) the following two lines which override the macOS defaults:

> SAVEHIST=0
> HISTSIZE=0

Ordinarily, one could put these changes into effect immediately by simply *sourcing* `~/.zshrc` (`. ~/.zshrc`). However, given Apple's predilection for *"improving"* `zsh`, a reboot may be a better idea.

This change should prevent both session history and the history file from accumulating any command history. Catalina/10.15 (at least mine) does not have a file(s) named `~/.zsh_sessions`. I don't know what its purpose is (other than possibly to retain session history?), but I don't *believe* it will override the above changes to `~/.zshrc`.

Try this if you care to, and let us know if it works on your system. There are other things to try - this one seems simplest.