# How can I set two separate Terminal profiles whereby one profile keeps a history and one doesn't?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I'm using zsh in macOS 13.

I sometimes want to just try out a few things in Terminal without wanting to keep any history or log of these once I close the Terminal window/tab. On other occasions I do want to keep the history though. So I created two profiles in Terminal, *History* and *No History* and then I launch whichever I need. I've even given both distinct background colours so I know which window is for testing.

I initially thought I'd do that upfront via `set +o history` under Preference > Profiles > Shell > Startup > Run, but that doesn't quite work.

I don't want to edit the `~/.zshrc` because that'd mean no history for those occasions where I do want to keep the history.

I've also tried `HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth` and then preceding each command with a space, meaning it won't get recorded, but that only seems to work in bash and it's only a workaround and not a solution anyway.

How can I keep no record / history for specified profiles once I close the Terminal window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/692913/temporarily-disable-history-in-zsh: you could try running the command `unset HISTFILE` on startup (instead of `set +o history`).

See also [How to disable .zsh_history & .zsh_sessions on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/434495/how-to-disable-zsh-history-zsh-sessions-on-macos) for another option.

(The first of these, `unset HISTFILE`, works for me. I haven't tried the second. This is with Ventura 13.0, in case the version of OS X matters.)

Comment: The nice thing about this solution is that I don't have to select "Terminate" at the end of the session.

Answer (score 2):

One way is set an environment variable in the run command for the profile.

e.g.

```
TTT=hello zsh -l
```

[image: Terminal.app Settings]

Then in ~/.zshrc test for that environment variable

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know what this command does? — I've had a look, but I don't have a ```.zshrc```, only a ```.zsh_history``` and a ```.zsh_sessions```.

Comment: It sets an environment variable TTT. You can test it with an if statement to alter history configuration. Use echo $TTT to see what its value is

Comment: Thanks, but what does setting TTT to ```hello``` bring about? And what is ```zsh -l``` for?

Comment: You need to look at some zsh tutorials as these are basic shell issues. Setting TTT allows zsh to use if statements depending on its value. zsh -l starts zsh as a login shell which is what Terminal.app does

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should've been clearer: I was wondering what if-statement is executed with TTT and why starting a login shell would not keep a history.

Comment: Those questions show that you need to read some tutorials as they are too long to answer in comments and possibly in answers here. See zsh manuals https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide.html

Comment: @AlexIxeras: You do have a text editor, don't you? So if you have not created a .zshrc yet, use the text editor to create the file...