# .zsh_sessions producing an error

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

Each time I open Terminal, I get an error:

```
/Users/myname/.zsh_sessions/SESSIONID.session:2: command not found: Saving
```

in each of the windows I set to open by default.  This seems to have appeared a week ago possibly with an OS update (Monterey)

I haven't touched anything in Terminal though.

This seems to be related to an error in the way the session file `SESSIONID.session` is written in `/Users/myname/.zsh_sessions/` when quitting Terminal

```
    (blank line)
    Saving session...echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r 1699309069)"
    (blank line)
```

Maybe a bug in `etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` or a configuration problem

Any idea?

EDIT:
I commented out the `echo -ne` line in `etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` and the problem disappeared

```
 shell_session_save() {
    # Save the current state.
    if [ -n "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE" ]; then
        # echo -ne '\nSaving session...' >&2
        (umask 077; echo 'echo Restored session: "$(/bin/date -r '$(/bin/date +%s)')"' >| "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE")
```

Comment: A similar (same?) problem was reported here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/465930/30895

Comment: Yes, it is related, there seems to be an error in  etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal, which I can't identify, possibly due to a personalised configuration or lack of.

Comment: One question. If you make a new user on the Mac, when you log out of the first and open a new graphical log in on the second, does the bug happen from the default setup and settings?

Comment: Also, be sure to put your solution in the answer section. Even if you don’t accept it it will help many

Comment: hello bmike, if I revert to the original  zshrc_Apple_Terminal and log in another user, the problem is gone. It seems there is a problem how STDERR is handled on my main account

Comment: Yes, it’s [essentially the same problem on bash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/465930/30895) in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`. Session save/restore has been in Terminal.app forever. What changed??? Do all of us seeing it has something similar (but not default) in our setups? Python? Homebrew? VS Code? …

Comment: (FWIW, I don’t consider [the other issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/465930/30895) “solved”!) If this Q is closed, perhaps upvote [that one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/465930/30895) for more attention?

Comment: _commented out the echo -ne line .... and the problem disappeared_ : The line by itself can't cause this error message. You can test it by putting it back in and manually calling `shell_session_save` from the command line. To make **this** echo in the end produce **that** error, it means that some process must collect the **standard error** of that function and execute it as command.

Comment: @user1934428: the problem is more specifically that stderr from that line is being (incorrectly) written to `$SHELL_SESSION_FILE` while the following `(…)` subshell is running; that file is then run (as it should) on the restart of Terminal.app, but with these incorrect characters in it.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe : This is clear, but this would mean that the caller of the function must have set up a redirection for file descriptor 2 to point to the session file. But even in this case, the `>| ` of the subsequent line would recreate the session file. I simply don't see how this effect can be achieved by the code posted here.

Comment: @Hugues: One thing which I would try is to replace the `echo` line by `print -u 2 $'\nSaving session ...'`, and then see whether the error is the same. Or maybe doing a `echo .... >$(tty)` instead. The latter really should not be redirected to any file, even if FD 2 is messed up somehow.

Comment: @user1934428, and yet it is! (Look at [the other thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/465930/30895) for a little more information.) In particular this code is run via `trap shell_session_update EXIT`, and the error seems to occurs only when the terminal exits because the Terminal.app is quit, but not by an explicit `exit` command (nor when various signals are sent by hand to the shell, either).

Comment: Your edit seems to be rather an answer, can you please post it as such beneath the other question?

Comment: @user1934428: commenting out the line actually makes the problem disappear; tested multiple times on 2 accounts. Your suggestion   print -u 2 $'\nSaving session ...'  also does.

Comment: @nohillside I'm not familiar with the usages in this forum, but for me it is not an answer but a workaround. As this seems to be a symptom of another problem. Anyway, the question having being closed, I can't add the answer now.

Comment: Please add the answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/465930/apple-terminal-startup-errors-session-save-restore

Comment: OK. I've done it