# Risk of uninstalling a customised zsh version

Tags: homebrew, zsh

Having been confronted to a minor bug on [Apple Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466160/zsh-sessions-producing-an-error), I followed naively an advice on an internet website recommending to update my shell zsh to latest version, using brew. Which I did. (and it did not solve the bug)

But now, I realise I have two versions of it.

The regular Apple one in `/bin/zsh` (5.8.1) and a new one in `/usr/local/bin/zsh` which redirects to `/usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.9/bin/zsh`

Is there a downside in uninstalling the brew-installed version again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, macOS doesn't care about custom-installed shells (I'm running a Homebrew-installed `bash` as my login shell since years), so there is no downside in keeping both versions installed, have shell scripts use `/bin/zsh` and use `/usr/local/bin/zsh` as your login shell in Terminal.

If you want to uninstall it anyway,

- check for any shell scripts starting with `!#/usr/local/bin/zsh` and change the she-bang back to `#!/bin/zsh`,
- check whether you set `/usr/local/bin/zsh` as your shell in Terminal or in any other application (e.g. BBEdit or Visual Code), and set it back to the standard version,
- check whether you changed your login shell with `chsh` and set it back to the standard version with `chsh -s /bin/zsh`,
- remove `/usr/local/bin/zsh` from `/etc/shells` if you had added it there,
- uninstall with `brew uninstall zsh`.

Comment: I've done as said

Answer (score -2):

This is a downside of *not* uninstalling the brew-installed version:

The $PATH variable which defines where your command is looked for, `/usr/local/bin` is usually explored before `/bin`. (the default in `etc/paths`)

This means that your personalised version of `zsh` will always be called by default in every bit of code or application that is calling directly for `zsh`.

This includes applications that do not have configuration parameters for `zsh` (e.g BBEdit), every application that have a default setting to use the default system `zsh` (e.g Terminal),  every line of code with a direct call to `zsh` (there can hundreds of them depending on what you do)

As a consequence, you need to be pretty sure of what you do when using your  own version installed by `brew`, including updating it manually to stay state of the art, including the case when you upgrade your Mac OS system and it updates the default `zsh` version without you being aware of it.

If you are using `zsh` casually, especially if you want to debug problems you are coming across with `zsh`, it is likely easier to work with the default version of the OS.