# How to turn off zsh automatically restore session in Terminal.app

Tags: terminal, zsh

This question is related to [How to turn off zsh save/restore session in Terminal.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458704/how-to-turn-off-zsh-save-restore-session-in-terminal-app). However, I don't want to shut down sessions completely setting `SHELL_SESSIONS_DISABLE=1` in my `.zshenv`. I want to keeps sessions, but just don't want to restore them automatically, when I open a new terminal. I also don't really get, when a session is restored and when not. This seems to happen kind of random.